# TFS: Removed Folder Mapping, but Mapping Still Shows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I'm having a hard time getting TFS to let go of some folder mappings.

I am working with Team Foundation Server for the first time. I have a folder tree on the server with lots of folders. I mapped a couple of project folders to local directories before I decided that I would rather just map the root folder, check recursive, and have it mimic the folder structure on the server.

After doing so, the lower level mappings were still there, so I decided to start from scratch. I removed all the mappings by right clicking on each mapped folder and choosing "Remove Mapping." Then I re-mapped the root folder with recursive checked.

The problem is that the original mappings still show up on the lower level folders. The "local path" shows the old local path rather than the new one.

I tried closing Visual Studio 2010 and deleting the folder C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0 and opening VS again. Still the old path shows.

I clicked on the Workspace dropdown -> workspaces... -> edit and removed any workspaces showing. Still the old path shows.

Does anyone know how to get around this? Where are these folder mappings even stored?

Comment: Where do you see this "local path"?  Did you do a get?  *TFS will remember what files you have downloaded locally when you change workspace mappings*.

Comment: Did you do a Get Latest after changing the mappings? They only get updated after you do. Very confusing.

Comment: I saw the local path above the file list when I highlighted the folder. No, I did not do a get latest after I changed the mapping. I thought it would get to the wrong location, but that fixed it! After I did a get latest, even though the local path showed incorrectly, the local path updated to reflect the new mapping! Thanks jessehouwing! Now back to trying to convince the office to switch to Hg.

Comment: @jessehouwing Would you post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After updating mappings Visual Studio will prompt you to do a "Get Latest Version", and it allows you to skip this step. Skipping this (or after a change from the commandline), a Get Latest Version (or Get Specific for that matter) is required to effectuate the changes to your mappings.